# how to fix "No qualifying bean of type 'com.newmvc.demo.queue.NewSender' available"

Tags: java, spring-boot

Im new to spring boot technology , I m building microservice, Im using jmstemplate for sending and receiving message in spring boot, but Im getting error "No qualifying bean of type 'com.newmvc.demo.queue.NewSender' available" and 
I have declared @Component in NewSender class

I have tired @Component annotation still it is showing same error

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableJms
public class Project1Application {
    @Bean
    public JmsListenerContainerFactory<?> jmsListenerContainerFactory(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
        DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer configurer) {
    DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory factory = new DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory();
    configurer.configure(factory, connectionFactory);
    return factory;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    SpringApplication.run(Project1Application.class, args);

    }}
```

this is my main application, Project1Application.class

```
package com.newmvc.demo.queue;

import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class MessageInt {
public static String Sendmessage(String xml) {
    ApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(MessageInt.class);
    NewSender sender = context.getBean(NewSender.class);
    sender.send("msgQueue", xml);
    return xml;
    }}
```

this is my message initializer class

```
@Component
public class NewSender {
@Autowired
    private JmsTemplate jmsTemplate;

    public void send(final String queue, final String msg) {
    jmsTemplate.convertAndSend(queue, msg);
    }
}
```

this is my sender class

```
  @Component
public class NewRecevier {

    @JmsListener(destination = "msgQueue", containerFactory = "jmsListenerContainerFactory")
    public void receiveMessage(String xml) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("Message Received\n\n");
    System.out.println("Message received from Queue: " + xml);

    }
}
```

this is my recevier class

In my controller class I have added @Componentscan{com.newmvc.demo.queue}

I expect the output as string should be received at receiver end

Im getting error like this

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.newmvc.demo.queue.NewSender' available
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:343) ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1123) ~[spring-context-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at com.newmvc.demo.queue.MessageInt.SendLog(MessageInt.java:15) ~[classes/:na]
    at newgateway.Gatewayy.updateLogs(Gatewayy.java:41) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.apache.jsp.updateresults_jsp._jspService(updateresults_jsp.java:135) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70) ~[tomcat-jasper-9.0.16.jar:9.0.16]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:476) ~[tomcat-jasper-9.0.16.jar:9.0.16]
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:385) ~[tomcat-jasper-9.0.16.jar:9.0.16]
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:329) ~[tomcat-jasper-9.0.16.jar:9.0.16]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) ~[spring-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:92) ~[spring-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200) ~[spring-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:200) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:490) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:834) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1415) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_181]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_181]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_181]
```

please help me out with this error,

Thanks in advance, any help would be appreciated

Comment: Did you add `@ComponentScan` in Configuration `Project1Application ` to your package with your defined beans ?

Comment: i have added in my controller class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh boy, there are some problems here.

Main cause for your error message is, that you're constructing an ApplicationContext with only one class/bean in it and trying to search for another bean in it (NewSender).

You have to do this as a member/field of the class and define it static:

```
ApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(MessageInt.class);
```

And try not creating the ApplicationContext in a way that you include every beans you'll need. So like this:

```
private static ApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext("com.mycompany.myfirm.myproject.mybeans");
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is:  In your MessageInt class, your are using static method. You are creating a new ApplicationContext instead of using spring already created one.  Spring beans are objects and cannot be used inside static methods.
Inside MessageInt class, create NewSender variable and autowire it or you can also create variable of Applicationcontext and autowire it which will inject actual spring application context.

```
@Component
public class MessageInt {

    @Autowired
    ApplicationContext context;

    public String Sendmessage(String xml) {
        NewSender sender = context.getBean(“NewSender”);
        sender.send("msgQueue", xml);
        return xml;
    }
}
```

Comment: it didn't work, i checked with your code thanks for response